# Why Aren't My ScriptControls Working in SharePoint?

Tags: visual-studio, javascript

I am a long-time ASP.NET developer but a first-time SharePoint developer. One of the most powerful features of ASP.NET custom scriptcontrols. Yet when I try to apply these controls to a custom SharePoint 2010 solution, i have run into nothing but trouble.

Most commonly, the script references are not loaded, so the script descriptors throw a "variable is undefined" error. Usually after I deploy the solution from visual studio, everything will work for only one request; script references are not loaded on additional requests. I have traced through my code & confirmed that my control's `GetScriptReferences` method is being called.

The following code is an example of a control i cannot get to work in Sharepoint 2010:

**HelloWorld.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: WebResource(Test.Controls.HelloWorld.ClientResource.Release, "text/javascript")]

namespace Test.Controls {
    public class HelloWorld : ScriptControl {

        public static class ClientResource {
            public const string Release = "Test.Controls.HelloWorld.js";
        }

        protected class HelloWorldScriptDescriptor : ScriptControlDescriptor {

            private const string ClientType = "Test.HelloWorld";

            public HelloWorldScriptDescriptor(HelloWorld control) : base(ClientType, control.ClientID) { }
        }

        public static readonly IEnumerable<ScriptReference> ScriptReferences = new ScriptReference[] {
            new ScriptReference(ClientResource.Release, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)
        };

        protected override IEnumerable<ScriptDescriptor> GetScriptDescriptors() {
            yield return new HelloWorldScriptDescriptor(this);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<ScriptReference> GetScriptReferences() {
            return ScriptReferences;
        }
    }
}
```

**HelloWorld.js**

```
Type.registerNamespace("Test");

Test.HelloWorld = function (element) {
    Test.HelloWorld.initializeBase(this, [element]);
};

Test.HelloWorld.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
        Test.HelloWorld.callBaseMethod(this, "initialize");
        this.get_element().innerHTML = "Hello World";
    }
};

Test.HelloWorld.registerClass("Test.HelloWorld", Sys.UI.Control);
```

**HelloWorldUserControl.ascx**

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HelloWorldUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Test.HelloWorld.HelloWorldUserControl" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="test" Namespace="Test.Controls" Assembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>

<test:HelloWorld ID="testHelloWorld" runat="server" />
```

This exact code works in an non-SharePoint ASP.NET web application.

I appreciate your time.

Comment: Can you explain what it is exactly that you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to add a custom script control (as described at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386450.aspx)) to a custom webpart in Visual Studio. The control above is a simple "Hello World" example that reproduces the issue i am having.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, `GetScriptReferences` cannot return my custom `ScriptReferences` property if it is static. Making it a non-static property resolved the issue. Not sure why it works in ASP.NET & not SharePoint.